# numpy: reorder array by specified values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix:

```
A = [ [1,2],
      [3,4],
      [5,6] ]
```

and a vector of values:

```
V = [4,6,2]
```

I would like to reorder A by 2nd column, using values from V. The result should
be:

```
A = [ [3,4],
      [5,6], 
      [1,2] ] # 2nd columns' values have the same order as V
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, we need to find the indicies of the values in the second column of `A` that we'd need to match the order of `V`.  In this case, that's `[1,2,0]`.  Once we have those, we can just use numpy's "fancy" indexing to do the rest.

So, you might do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(6).reshape((3,2)) + 1
V = [4,6,2]
column = A[:,1].tolist()
order = [column.index(item) for item in V]
print A[order,:]
```

If you want to avoid python lists entirely, then you can do something like what's shown below. It's hackish, and there may be a better way, though...

We can abuse `numpy.unique` to do this... What I'm doing here is depending on a particular implementation detail (`unique` seems to start at the end of the array) which could change  at any time... That's what makes it an ugly hack.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(6).reshape((3,2)) + 1
V = np.array([4,6,2])
vals, order = np.unique(np.hstack((A[:,1],V)), return_inverse=True)
order = order[-V.size:]
print A[order,:]
```

Comment: Well, there is, but it seems that you don't want `A` sorted by `V`... (If you did, you'd just need to use `np.argsort` and then use indexing, or another similar method.) You want `A` in the same order as `V`.  Then again, there probably is a simpler way than what I'm describing...

Answer (score 6):

[@JoeKington's numpy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891247/numpy-reorder-array-by-specified-values/7892028#7892028) is very clever, but it relies on `A[:,1]` being in sorted order. Here is a fix for the general case:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
N=5
A = np.arange(2*N).reshape((-1,2))+100
np.random.shuffle(A)
print(A)
```

If `A` looks like this:

```
[[104 105]
 [102 103]
 [108 109]
 [100 101]
 [106 107]]
```

and `V`

```
V = A[:,1].copy()
np.random.shuffle(V)
print(V)
```

looks like this:

```
[105 109 107 101 103]
```

then we use Joe's solution:

```
vals, order = np.unique(np.hstack((A[:,1],V)), return_inverse=True)
```

but save both the order of `A[:,1]` and `V`:

```
a_order = order[:V.size]
v_order = order[-V.size:]
```

and sort `A` (by forming `A[np.argsort(a_order)]`) before reordering with `v_order`:

```
print A[np.argsort(a_order)][v_order]

[[104 105]
 [108 109]
 [106 107]
 [100 101]
 [102 103]]
```

(`A[np.argsort(a_order)]` is `A` sorted according to its second column.)

---

Note that np.unique always returns the array in sorted order. [The documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) guarantees with `return_inverse=True` that the returned indices are the indices of the unique array that reconstructs the original array. That is, if you call `np.unique` like this:

```
uniq_arr, indices = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
```

you are guaranteed that

```
unique_arr[indices] = arr
```

Because you can rely on this relationship, Joe's method does not depend on a mere implementation detail -- `unique` will always behave this way. (Famous last words -- considering what happened to the [order of output arguments](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/55d07fbe7b06ebe34511d53c4cabab8c9476d0ff/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L428) returned by `np.unique1d` ... but never mind that :))

Comment: Quite nice, and good points in all cases! I wasn't thinking it through enough.