# np.array([0, 0, 0]) [ [1, 2, 2] ] += [4, 5, 6] does not accumulate

Tags: numpy, array-indexing

All arrays in the following are NumPy arrays.

I have an array of numbers, say `a = [4, 5, 6]`.
I want to add them to an accumulation array, say `s = [0, 0, 0]`
but I want to control which number goes to where.
For instance, I want

- `s[1] += a[0]`,
- `s[2] += a[1]`, and then
- `s[2] += a[2]`.

So I set up an auxiliary array `i = [1, 2, 2]`
and hope that `s[i] += a` would work.
But it wouldn't;
`s[2]` end up only receiving `a[2]`,
as if `s[i] += a` is implemented by
`t = [0, 0, 0]; t[i] = a; s += t`.

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve my version of "`s[i] += a`"
without having to do for-loops in pure python,
as I heard that the latter is much slower.

Comment: Maybe this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891247/numpy-reorder-array-by-specified-values

Comment: Look at `np.add.at`.  This does an unbuffered adition tbat does what you want with duplicate indices.  I can elwborate, but  I think the docs are clear enough.

Comment: @h that's exactly what I want.  Thank you.